# Derivative of LASSO function

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, statistics

Denote the criterion function by

$$Q_\lambda(\beta) = || Y - X\beta ||_2^2 /n + \lambda ||\beta||_1$$

The above is LASSO.

Now I am asking the ordinary first derivative at $\hat{\beta}(\lambda)$.

$$\frac{\partial Q_\lambda(\beta)}{\partial \beta_j} |_{\beta=\hat{\beta}(\lambda)} = -2 X_j^T (Y-X\beta)/n + \lambda sign  (\beta_j) |_{\beta=\hat{\beta}(\lambda)}=0 $$

I don't know how to get the derivative of $\lambda ||\beta||_1  $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\|\beta\|_1 = |\beta_1| + \cdots + |\beta_d|$, so you only need to focus on taking the derivative of $|\beta_j|$.

The absolute value function $\beta_j \mapsto |\beta_j|$ is differentiable everywhere except at $\beta_j=0$. When $\beta_j \ne 0$, the derivative is the sign of $\beta_j$. (The absolute value function is piecewise linear.)